# function is in one of object files but linker doesn't link them

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

friends, I have a question about linking. I have a problem with linking the project. 
I have tree of files:

```
ffmpeg4.1_custom
    fftools 
         ffmpeg.o  
    libavfilter
         libavfilter.so.
```

make has only one command to finish - this:

```
$ make -n
printf "LD\t%s\n" ffmpeg_g; gcc -Llibavcodec -Llibavdevice -Llibavfilter -Llibavformat -Llibavresample -Llibavutil -Llibpostproc -Llibswscale -Llibswresample -L/usr/local/lib  -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-rpath-link=libpostproc:libswresample:libswscale:libavfilter:libavdevice:libavformat:libavcodec:libavutil:libavresample   -o ffmpeg_g fftools/ffmpeg_opt.o fftools/ffmpeg_filter.o fftools/ffmpeg_hw.o fftools/cmdutils.o fftools/ffmpeg.o  -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavcodec -lavresample -lpostproc -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil  -lm -lxcb -lxcb-shape -lxcb-xfixes -lasound -lSDL2 -lsndio -lXv -lX11 -lXext -pthread -lm -lva -lm -lz -lssl -lcrypto -lvpx -lm -lvpx -lm -lvpx -lm -lvpx -lm -pthread -lm -llzma -lz -lfdk-aac -lopenjp2 -lx264 -lva -lm -lm -lm -lm -pthread -lva-drm -lva -lva-x11 -lva -lm -lva -lXv -lX11 -lXext -ldl  
printf "STRIP\t%s\n" ffmpeg; strip -o ffmpeg ffmpeg_g
```

I check my function in ffmpeg.o:

```
$ nm fftools/ffmpeg.o | grep my_func
                 U my_func
```

I check the same in libavfilter.so:

```
$ nm libavfilter/libavfilter.so | grep my_func
00000000000b2f8e t my_func
```

I run full command that links these 2 files:

```
$ gcc -Llibavcodec -Llibavdevice -Llibavfilter -Llibavformat -Llibavresample -Llibavutil -Llibpostproc -Llibswscale -Llibswresample -L/usr/local/lib  -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-rpath-link=libpostproc:libswresample:libswscale:libavfilter:libavdevice:libavformat:libavcodec:libavutil:libavresample   -o ffmpeg_g fftools/ffmpeg_opt.o fftools/ffmpeg_filter.o fftools/ffmpeg_hw.o fftools/cmdutils.o fftools/ffmpeg.o  -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavcodec -lavresample -lpostproc -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil  -lm -lxcb -lxcb-shape -lxcb-xfixes -lasound -lSDL2 -lsndio -lXv -lX11 -lXext -pthread -lm -lva -lm -lz -lssl -lcrypto -lvpx -lm -lvpx -lm -lvpx -lm -lvpx -lm -pthread -lm -llzma -lz -lfdk-aac -lopenjp2 -lx264 -lva -lm -lm -lm -lm -pthread -lva-drm -lva -lva-x11 -lva -lm -lva -lXv -lX11 -lXext -ldl
fftools/ffmpeg.o: In function `configure_filtergraph':
ffmpeg.c:(.text+0x6892): undefined reference to `my_func'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If it plays any role, my function's prototype is in avfilter.h, code is in avfilter.c and it is used in ffmpeg.c
What am I doing wrong?

Linux Mint 19
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)

Comment: Are you sure that you link with `libavfilter/libavfilter.so`? Perhaps specify the library explicitly with the path instead (i.e. change `-lavfilter` to `libavfilter/libavfilter.so`)?

Comment: The "t" in the nm output for libavfilter.so indicates that the symbol is not exported (it would be "T" otherwise). You need to ensure it's exported, before you can use it externally (using `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` eg.).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, I tried to do it, unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried to add it to both .h and .c, no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'nm' output indicate my_func is "local" to libavfilter.so  - it is marked with 't'. You can only refer to "global" functions - those will be marked with 'T'

From nm man page:

> The symbol type.  At least the following types are used; others are, as well, depending on the object file
>              format.  If lowercase, the symbol is usually local; if uppercase, the symbol is global (external).  There
>              are however a few lowercase symbols that are shown for special global symbols ("u", "v" and "w").

Access to local symbols is limited to the same module.